# Showing that $R^3/R^1$ is two dimensional space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we have a equivalence relation:

$x\sim y \in R^3$
if
$x-y \in R^1$

How should we show that $R^3/R^1$ is two dimensional space if we know that $R^1$ is subspace of $R^3$?

I think we should prove it with fundamental theorem of homomorphim

Comment: Do you mean homeomorphic as topological spaces?  Why the topology tag?  This sounds like a linear algebra question.

Comment: Show that that the equivalence classes of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ form a vector space basis.

Comment: @saulspatz I face it in an topology lecture note but I don’t know how is the proof

Comment: @William would you please explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely (linear) algebraically we see that $\mathbb{R}^3{/}V \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$, when $V$ is a one-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If we look at the quotient map $q$ sending $x \in \Bbb R^3$ to $x+V$ in the quotient space, which is linear, of course, and has a one-dimensional kernel ($V$) and as the domain has dimension $3$, so the [Rank-Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) implies that the dimension of the image, i.e. the space $\Bbb R^3{/}V$ must equal $2$, so is essentially $\Bbb R^2$ (all $2$-dimensional real vector spaces are), also topologically (the finite-dimensionality implies this).

Comment: How should we show that topologically …

Comment: @armankashef It's a standard theorem. You could prove this instance of it by showing an isometry with $\Bbb R^2$, using norms, but why bother?

Comment: Because the notes write this example after fundamental theorem of homomorphism. But i don’t know about the map I need

Comment: @armankashef Find a linear map from the quotient to $\Bbb R^2$. It will depend on the copy of $\Bbb R^1$ (or $V$) that you choose.

Comment: What did you mean of copy¿ should I use a canonical map¿

Comment: @armankashef find a base, e.g. It won't be canonical. It you have such a $T$ compose it with $q$ to check continuity.

Comment: Is there any source that I can see some similar way of yours ¿

Comment: And we can say that for $R^3/R^2$ too . Is there any correspondence in 3d cartesian space¿

Answer (score 0):

Consider map $f:R^3 \to R^3/R$ by $f(v)=v+R$, then the null space of $f$ is $R$ so by rank and nullity theorem, the Image $R^3/R$ is of dimension $2$ as $dim(im(f))+dim(null(f))=dim(R^3)=3$ and $dim(null(f))=dim(R)=1$

Comment: The equivalence class is not important in this solution ¿